# MATLAB compute average value corresponding to each column number in matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose I have the following array:

```
A=[1 2
   1 4
   2 6
   3 5
   5 7
   1 9
   2 7];
```

What is the most efficient (preferably one-liner) way in MATLAB to automatically obtain a matrix which holds the average value of the second column elements for every unique element in the first column? The result for `A` above would be:

```
B=[1 mean([2 4 9])
   2 mean([6 7])
   3 mean([5])
   5 mean([7])];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) can generate the first column while the powerful [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) equipped with the `mean` function will calculate the second (`nonzeros` is called for non-existent indices like `4` in this case):

```
>> B = [unique(A(:,1)),nonzeros(accumarray(A(:,1),A(:,2),[],@mean))]
B =
    1.0000    5.0000
    2.0000    6.5000
    3.0000    5.0000
    5.0000    7.0000
```

---

As noted in the comments by [dan-man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2399799/dan-man), the above approach only works if the first column always has integer values (I guess I implied this use-case from the given example; apologies).  You can use `unique` to get around the shortcoming as follows:

```
[Aunq,~,Aind] = unique(A(:,1));
B = [Aunq,accumarray(Aind,A(:,2),[],@mean))];
```

Further pointed out was the fact that due to how `accumarray` works internally, calling `mean` directly is not as efficient as performing the calculation more directly:

```
B = [Aunq,accumarray(Aind,A(:,2),[],@sum)./accumarray(Aind,1,[],@sum)]
```

Comment: `accumarray` will fail if `A(:,1)` contains anything other than smallish positive integers.  But you can get round this problem easily by replacing `A(:,1)`, with the third output of `unique(A(:,1))`.  And then you can also drop the wrapping `nonzeros` call.

Comment: Also, if performance is relevant I recommend replacing `accumarray(...@mean)` with `accumarray(...,@sum) ./ accumarray(...1,[],@sum)`, i.e. calculate sum and counts and divide manually. Last time I checked this was a lot faster because `accumarray` is not optimized for use with `@mean` .

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
B=[];for k=unique(A(:,1)).';B=[B;k sum((A(:,1)==k).*A(:,2))/sum((A(:,1)==k))];end
```